# Solving an equation with two parameters for many pairs of the parameters

Tags: equation-solving

I have the equation:

```
tau == (8.183*10^-4) * Sqrt[Pi] * Sqrt[T]*U^-1.5 * E^(U/T)
```

where I am trying to solve for `U` but I have multiple pairs of `tau` and `T`.  I was wondering how the best way to numerically solve for all the `U`s I get from the lists of `tau` and `T` so I don't have to enter the `tau`s and `T`s one at a time.

Comment: This will throw errors about using `InverseFunction`, which implies that some of the solutions might be thrown away, but you can use `Solve` on this equation to get a closed form expression for `U` in terms of `ProductLog`. After that, just make a `Table` over the values of `tau` and `T`.

Comment: Yeah, it is 8.183 * 10^-4

Answer (score 2):

Inverse functions of differentiable function satisfy [a well-known differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#The_inverse_function_rule). We can exploit that by solving this ODE with `NDSolve`:

This is the function that maps a $T$ to a mapping $f_T \colon U \mapsto \tau$).

```
τFun = T \[Function] (U \[Function] (8.183*10^-4)*Sqrt[Pi]*Sqrt[T]*U^-1.5*E^(U/T));
```

And this is the function that maps each $T$ to $f_T^{-1} \colon \tau \mapsto U$ (or rather its restriction to the interval from `τa` to `τb`:

```
UFun = T \[Function] Block[{S = T, u, τ, U0 = 1.},
    NDSolveValue[
     Evaluate[{D[u[τ], τ] == 1/τFun[S]'[u[τ]], u[τFun[S][U0]] == U0}],
     u, 
     {τ, τa, τb}],
     PrecisionGoal -> 15
    ];
```

Sanity check:

```
f = τFun[1/10];
finv = UFun[1/10];
Plot[f[finv[τ]] - τ, {τ, τa, τa + 1}]
```

[image]

Admittedly, this method is not very precise...

As an application we can plot the family of inverse functions like this

```
Manipulate[
 With[{U = UFun[T]}, 
  Plot[U[τ], {τ, 1., 20.}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, .1}]], {T, 
  0.1, 1000}]
```

**Final remark**

Originally, I aimed at using `ParametricNDSolveValue` as this is precisly one of the application it was made for. Unfortunately. I did not get it working `ParametricNDSolveValue`. Maybe somebody else knows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an exact exponent (almost always needed for `Solve`, it seems), you get three solutions, the first of which is real:

```
Solve[tau == (8.183*10^-4)*Sqrt[Pi]*Sqrt[T]*U^(-3/2)*E^(U/T), U]
(*
  {{U -> -1.5 T ProductLog[-(0.00854215/(T^(2/3) tau^(2/3)))]},
   {U -> -1.5 T ProductLog[(0.00427107 - 0.00739772 I)/(T^(2/3) tau^(2/3))]},
   {U -> -1.5 T ProductLog[(0.00427107 + 0.00739772 I)/(T^(2/3) tau^(2/3))]}}
*)
```

So `{U -> -1.5 T ProductLog[-(0.00854215/(T^(2/3) tau^(2/3)))]}` is the real solution (for position `T` and `tau`).  You can plug in values like this:

```
{U -> -1.5` T ProductLog[-(0.00854214749414121`/(T^(2/3) tau^(2/3)))]} /.
  {T -> 1., tau -> 2.}
(*  {U -> 0.00811561}  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f[{tau_, T_}] := Evaluate[U /. 
   First@Solve[tau == (8.183*10^-4)*Sqrt[Pi]*Sqrt[T]*U^-1.5*E^(U/T), U]]
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {25, 2}]
f /@ pts
```

Comment: This works so much as it ends up being that there are two solutions and this only gets me the lowest solution.  Do you know how I would go about getting the higher one?  I think it has to do with a problem with ProductLog only gives the lowest order solution.  If I try and do higher order solutions of ProductLog, I get imaginary components though I know my solution should be completely real.

Comment: @JamesD Given`T>0` and anticipating `U>0` you can set `z=U/T` and solve for `z`: `Solve[tau == (8.183*10^-4)*Sqrt[Pi]*1/T z^-(3/2) E^z, z]`.